# How to use scrollIntoView in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use links in my header to scroll to different parts of my App with scrollIntoView. The header is a child of App. I am getting a TypeError saying the variable I am trying to save the id to is undefined. Can someone please help me to determine what I am doing wrong? I think I may have to use ComponentDidMount, but I'm not sure how to do it, if that is even the fix. I am going to have to do this with all my header links.

//ERROR
    bundle.js:152 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of 
    null
    at App.getScrollLocations (bundle.js:152)
    at onClick (bundle.js:19957)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:4660)
    at executeDispatch (bundle.js:4460)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (bundle.js:4483)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (bundle.js:3913)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (bundle.js:3924)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at forEachAccumulated (bundle.js:4760)
    at Object.processEventQueue (bundle.js:4129)
///////

//App

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.getScrollLocations = this.getScrollLocations.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      open: false,
      projects: Service,
      selectedProject: Service[0]
    }
  }

  closeModal(event) {
    this.setState({open: false});
  }

  openModal(project) {
    this.setState({
      open: true,
      selectedProject: project
    });
  }
    ///////////// scroll function //////////////
  getScrollLocations() {
    const whatIDo = document.getElementById('.whatIdo');
    console.log(whatIDo)
    whatIDo.scrollIntoView();
  }

  render() {
    const show = {
      display: 'block'
    };
    const hide = {
      display: 'none'
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={this.state.open === false ? hide : show}>
          <Modal
            value={this.state.open}
            closeModal={this.closeModal}
            project={this.state.selectedProject}
          />
        </div>
        <Header
          //////////// FUNCTION PASSED TO HEADER ///////////////
          getScrollLocations={this.getScrollLocations}
        />
        <Intro />
        /////////////// ELEMENT I AM TARGETING /////////////////
        <WhatIDo id="whatIDo" />
        <WhoIAm />
        <Gallery
          value={this.state.open}
          projects={this.state.projects}
          openModal={this.openModal}
        />
        <Contact />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

//Header

```
const header = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header-name">
         XXXXXXX XXXXXXX
      </div>

      <div className="header-links">
        <ul>
          <li>Intro</li>
          <li
            ///////////// FUNCTION CALL ON CLICK /////////////////
            onClick={() => props.getScrollLocations()}
          >What I do</li>
          <li>Who I am</li>
          <li>My Work</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/icd2k3/react-scroll-into-view-if-needed

Answer (score 5):

I used the following module to achieve this in react:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view-if-needed

It works much as you'd expect using in-page anchor links and can be used with react-router without problems.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import scrollIntoViewIfNeeded from 'scroll-into-view-if-needed';

/*
SCROLL INTO VIEW

Purpose:
  This modular component enables hash links
  eg. (www.xyz.com/somepage#someID)
  and plays nice with react router 4

Usage:
  Wrap this component around a single div with an ID

Example:
  <ScrollIntoView  id={this.props.location.hash}>
    <div id="someID">
      ... loads of content...
    </div>
  </ScrollIntoView>

  <a href="/somepage#someID"> IN-PAGE ANCHOR </a>

 */

class ScrollIntoView extends React.Component {


  componentDidMount() {
    this.scroll();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scroll();
  }

  scroll() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    //console.log('ID is: '+id);
    if (!id) {
      return;
    }
    const element = document.querySelector(id);
    if (element) {
      // this just jumps to the element
      // see support:
      //element.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});

      //If Firefox...
      if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
        //...use native smooth scrolling.
        element.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});
      // If its any other browser, use custom polyfill...
      }else{
        //... luckily I have this handy polyfill...
        scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(element, false, {
          duration: 150
        });
        //  (⌐■_■
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
ScrollIntoView.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    PropTypes.object.isRequired
  ])
};
export default ScrollIntoView;
```

Here is an example of that in action:
https://anthonycregan.co.uk/portfolio

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: What is this file: import scrollIntoViewIfNeeded from 'scroll-into-view-if-needed';?

Comment: That is a module that detects whether the browser the page is being rendered in supports ScrollIntoView natively, if the browser does support scrollIntoview then the module does nothing, if scrollIntoView is not supported by the users browser, this module provides a polyfill to enable that feature. 

More documentation on this module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view-if-needed

Browser Support for ScrollIntoView:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Comment: ahh ok. Thanks again.