# Use history.goBack to restore previous scroll position in React Router 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, html5-history

In my SPA, I have a list of `<Link>` that point to a Viewer component route that uses `withRouter`.  When the user navigates to the Viewer, withRouter pushes state and history to it.  In the Viewer, I am using

```
this.props.history.goBack()
```

in a `<BackArrow>` component, and it works to restore the location, but not the scroll position in the list and returns the window to the top.

Is this expected with `goBack()`?

AFAIK, using `scrollIntoView` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677725/how-to-use-scrollintoview-in-react) will not work with  since `ref` cannot be assigned to functional components, and `getElementById` cannot find an `id` assigned to a component rendered element.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this?